# How can i make font-weight bold in input filed without changing the placeholder font-weight?

Tags: css

If I want to make an input fields' text bold but not the placeholder, what should I do?

If I give 'font-weight:bold' in the input field, the placeholder of the input field becomes also bold. I want the text of the input field to be bold, not the placeholder

Comment: `input::placeholder{font-weight:normal;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the pseudo-element `::placeholder`. Should be supported by most modern browsers.

```css
input {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Type Here"/>
```

Comment: It is not supported by some few versions of browsers but no problem. It worked for me.